# How to fix or debug distributed container registry mirroring?

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm trying to [install](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/install/registry_and_cache_servers.html#install-a-proxy-container-registry) and [use](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/autoscale.html#distributed-container-registry-mirroring) a "distributed container registry mirror" for my autoscaling GitLab Runner, as documented by GitLab. Here is the relevant portion of my `config.toml`:

```
[[runners]]
  name = "linux-c5.2xlarge"
  limit = 40
  url = "https://gitlab.com/"
  token = "redacted"
  executor = "docker+machine"
  [runners.docker]
    tls_verify = false
    image = "redacted"
    privileged = false
    disable_entrypoint_overwrite = false
    oom_kill_disable = false
    disable_cache = true
    shm_size = 0
  [runners.cache]
    Type = "s3"
    Path = "redacted"
    Shared = true
    [runners.cache.s3]
      ServerAddress = "s3.amazonaws.com"
      AccessKey = "redacted"
      SecretKey = "redacted"
      BucketName = "redacted"
      BucketLocation = "us-east-2"
  [runners.machine]
    IdleCount = 0
    IdleTime = 300
    MachineDriver = "amazonec2"
    MachineName = "linux-c5.2xlarge-%s"
    MachineOptions = [
      "amazonec2-access-key=redacted",
      "amazonec2-secret-key=redacted",
      "amazonec2-ami=ami-0b316c366679a59d7",
      "amazonec2-region=us-east-2",
      "amazonec2-zone=c",
      "amazonec2-use-private-address=true",
      "amazonec2-security-group=gitlab-runners",
      "amazonec2-instance-type=c5.2xlarge",
      "amazonec2-request-spot-instance=true",
      "amazonec2-spot-price=0.20",
      "engine-registry-mirror=http://172.31.43.207:6000"
    ]
    OffPeakTimezone = ""
    OffPeakIdleCount = 0
    OffPeakIdleTime = 0
```

Both my runner and my container registry mirror are running on the same machine with private IP 172.31.43.207.

```
$ hostname --ip-address
172.31.43.207

$ sudo docker container ls
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
1975ab504374        registry:2          "/entrypoint.sh /etc…"   5 hours ago         Up 5 hours          0.0.0.0:6000->5000/tcp   registry
```

But my images keep getting pulled from Docker Hub. I can see the download count rising by my number of jobs for every new pipeline, and the registry mirror appears empty:

```
$ curl http://172.31.43.207:6000/v2/_catalog
{"repositories":[]}
```

Does this feature work for anyone else? What am I doing wrong? Is there any way to debug this? Any relevant log I can check? Thanks in advance!